# I want to seperate first name last name and age from my string in sas

Tags: sas

**Input:**

```
David30Miller   
Jhonty45Rhodes  
Ahsley63Cummins
```

So first name variable should contain the character before the age i.e David Age should contain the number i.e 30 and last name should contain the Miller.

**Required Output:**

```
FirstName Age Last name  
David     30  Miller 
Jhonty    45  Rhodes  
Ahsley    63  Cummins
```

Can somebody help?

Comment: What have you tried?  Right now this doesn't look like a good question, particularly as even a small amount of research could at least come up with a few possibilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Step1:** Extract age by using **compress(string,,"kd")** (where kd compresses all the character values leaving us with the age)
**Step2:** Using age as a parameter for **scan** function to make first name and last name. scan(,,) : First parameter is the value you want to work upon, second parameter being which part of the string you want to extract and the third parameter is which symbol is used for differentiating (age) in this case.

```
data abc;
input string $50.;
cards;
David30Miller
Jhonty45Rhodes
Ahsley63Cummins
;
run;

data abc;
set abc;
age = input(compress(string,,"kd"),best.);
first_name =scan(string,1,age);  /*or scan(string,1,,"d");*/
last_name = scan(string,2,age);  /*or scan(string,2,,"d");*/
run;
```

**My Output:**

```
|string             |age    |first_name   |last_name
|David30Miller      |30     |David        |Miller
|Jhonty45Rhodes     |45     |Jhonty       |Rhodes
|Ahsley63Cummins    |63     |Ahsley       |Cummins
```

let me know in case of any queries

Comment: A good answer in Stack Overflow is not code-only, as this is, but explains the how - teaches, not gives.

Comment: Can't believe you down voted the correct answer of the person who is trying to help you. And i was explaining the answer, if you could have waited for 30 more seconds. Anyways let me know in case you don't understand any part of the code. Always happy to help.

Comment: DV was me, not OP.  And I think this is a bit better, but please read [faq] and [answer]; this is still very much just giving code to someone who's asked a poor question.  I'd also suggest that there's no reason to use age in the scan function; that's poor design, as it causes an unnecessary num-char conversion.  Use `'d'` fourth argument instead.

Comment: Finally - write a _complete_ answer before submitting, don't just put something in then plan to improve.  That's called "fastest gun in the west" and is very much considered improper here.  Submit the answer when you've completed it; waiting five more minutes to hit submit doesn't hurt anyone.

Comment: I am new to this platform. I did not expect such rude comments coming from such an experienced guy like you. Anyways was just trying to help someone who was in need. Will keep your points in mind.

Comment: Comments are limited (think twitter) so not a ton of room for 'polite' talk, but apologies if they came across rude.  Your answer is better now, though I'd encourage you to format it with paragraphs - again read [answer].  And I'd still encourage you to use `scan(string,1,,'d')` rather than using age for the scan delimiter.

Comment: @G.Arima I don't know about others but I sure learned something today. Something which I didn't know earlier. You initial post (without so many edits) was enough for me to get started and go and explore on my own. I know you did you put your best foot forward.Thanks a lot for that:-)

Comment: Thanks! will try to improve the question from the next time

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Prxchange as shown below. Below is brief discussion about the code.

```
 ^([a-z]+)([0-9]+)([a-z]+)$ --- ^ means starting ^([a-z]+) this is group1 with 
 alphabets

 ([0-9]+) is group2 with numbers only

 ([a-z]+)$  is group3. 

 $1 represents group1 which can replace everything with group 1 by using /$1/
  $2 represents group1 which can replace everything with group 2 by using /$2/
 $3 represents group1 which can replace everything with group 3 by using /$3/
```

In first scenario we replace everything with group one gives your firstname and so on

```
data want
set have;
firstname = prxchange('s/^([a-z]+)([0-9]+)([a-z]+)$/$1/i',1,trim(string));
age = input(prxchange('s/^([a-z]+)([0-9]+)([a-z]+)$/$2/i',2,trim(string)),8.);;
lastname = prxchange('s/^([a-z]+)([0-9]+)([a-z]+)$/$3/i',1,trim(string));;
run;
```